# Docker Desktop - Windows Hypervisor is not present

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have problem about "Docker-Desktop". you can see problem in the image. I am not good with windows, or if i can install docker cli in windows help me this way. Thanks For Helping!

[fa](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmUpN.png)

i try everything like google,chatgpt, youtube, groups. i dont know everything xd

Comment: Have you tried Googling this issue?

Comment: Don't paste images, use text.  Here's why: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1847378